# F# async try with not catching exceptions

Tags: f#

Strange things... I just wanted to do a simple retry on exceptions in F# but the catch doesn't catch :) Any ideas?

```ml
let rec retry times next event =
    async {
        try
            return! next event
        with
        | _ when times > 0 -> return! retry (times - 1) next event
        | error -> return error.Reraise()
    }
```

if the next is a function like;
`let handler evt = async { failwith "Oh-no" }`
Then the code in try executes but it is not catched. What is going on? :O

### UPDATE

The reraise is an extension method as described here: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/660 by nikonthethird.

```ml
type Exception with
    member this.Reraise () =
        (ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture this).Throw ()
        Unchecked.defaultof<_>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does catch the exceptions. Here's the full program I'm running to test it:

```ml
let rec retry times next event =
    async {
        try
            printfn "Retry: %A" times
            return! next event
        with
        | _ when times > 0 -> return! retry (times - 1) next event
        | error -> raise error
    }

let handler evt =
    async {
        printfn "About to fail once"
        failwith "Oh-no"
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    retry 3 handler ()
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> printfn "%A"
    0
```

Output:

```
Retry: 3
About to fail once
Retry: 2
About to fail once
Retry: 1
About to fail once
Retry: 0
About to fail once
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Oh-no
```

You can see that the exceptions are being caught, because `handler` is invoked multiple times before `retry` gives up.

Notes:

- I replaced `return error.Reraise()` with `raise error`, since `Exception.Reraise` isn't a defined method. I'm not sure what you had in mind here, but it doesn't directly affect the answer to your question.
- It's important to fully invoke `retry` with all three arguments (I used `()` as the "event"), and then run the resulting `async` computation synchronously. Maybe you weren't doing that?
- You might want to look into using [`Async.Catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/asynchronous-and-concurrent-programming/async#asynccatch) for handling async exceptions instead.

Comment: it's recommended to use `rethrow()` or `reraise()` instead of `raise exception` , because latter changes stacktrace

Comment: Actually, `reraise` isn't allowed here, presumably because it's inside a computation expression. (The compiler error isn't clear: `Calls to 'reraise' may only occur directly in a handler of a try-with`.) In any case, as I mentioned, it's not directly relevant to OP's question.

Comment: So I think I have to apologize, it works indeed. My test case running this code had the bug :D This remind me of a question; Who gonna test your tests?  Thank You @brianberns for Your time on that.

Comment: Thx for Async.Catch - didn't know that one! Will check it.